# Geomesa Accumulo field visibility without users

Tags: geomesa

I have got my Geomesa install working so I can create a schema, write data to it and then retrieve it.  The next step I need to do is to set field level visibility.  I have followed the example and it looks like it is working since I get nothing back (all fields have a visibility) but I need to be able to query and set the visibility programmatically.  It will eventually be behind an api and visibility will be determined based on a number of factors so I don't want to have "users" of accumulo, I just want to be able to set it.

I can not find any examples of how to do this in java.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally only have one Accumulo user, and then implement an [AuthorizationsProvider](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/datastores/security.html#reading-visibility-labels), which is responsible for setting the auths for any given request. There is a full example using LDAP to source authorizations provided in the [GeoMesa documentation](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/tutorials/geomesa-examples-authorizations.html).